# How to get a value within a list inside a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I've a dataframe which has a column of list -

```
print(df)
```

| Index | Name |
| --- | --- |
| [{'cadence': '2022-12-07 14:02:28.012', 'id': 'RJASTD'}] | Sarah |
| [{'cadence': '2022-12-07 14:02:28.012', 'id': 'NMRFAS'}] | James |

```
print(f"value: {df['Index'][0]}")  # value: [{'cadence': '2022-12-07 14:02:28.012', 'id': 'RJASTD'}]
print(f"length: {len(df['Index'][0])}")  # length: 1
print(f"type: {type(df['Index'][0])}")  # type: <class 'list'>
```

I want to extract a part of the values from lists and put them in another column -

| Index1 | Name |
| --- | --- |
| RJASTD | Sarah |
| NMRFAS | James |

How to get such derived column?

I tried with lstrip() and replace() but I must be missing out on something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
df['index1] = df['index'].str[0].str['id']
```